# How to create a numerical range using formula in Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[image]
I want to do it like the attached image.
If you specify a start number and an end number, it dynamically fills the numerical range.
How do you achieve this?

Comment: Use `=SEQUENCE(1,1+P2-O2,O2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @JvdV has pointed out, you can use the `SEQUENCE` function:

```
=SEQUENCE(1,(B2-A2)+1,A2)
```

**Notice** You have to add +1 to the columns to get the full range.

[image: Formula Example]

###### Documentation:

- [SEQUENCE FUNCTION](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244?hl=en)